# Variable with $state - Jasmine Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

First, I never seen Angular and Jasmine until several months ago. So I spend two or three months studying this in the practices of a company, and finally they've sent me to try test a controller/service in Visual Studio Code.

I have this variable in the controller:

```
vm.option = $state.param.option;
```

And in the spec.js I create a `it` with this:

```
it('"option" should be defined', function () {
 expect(ctrl.option).toBeDefined();
});
```

Previously, I inject in `beforeEach` a `$controller`, `$rootScope`, `_$log_`, `$injector` and the service. I need something special for test this variable? I tried inject `_$state_` but the message `Expected undefined to be defined` appears too.

I appreciate all help, and sorry for my bad english.

Edit:

The spec.js :

```
'use strict';
describe('app/specs/spec.js', function () {
 var scope, $log, service, ctrl, state/*, testedStateExample*/;
 beforeAll(function () {} );
 beforeEach(angular.mock.module('App.moduleExample'));
 beforeEach(function () {
  module(function ($provide){
   $provide.constnt('APP_CONFIG', {});
  });
 });
 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($controller, $state, $rootScope, _$log_, _service_){
  service = _service_;
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $log = _$log_;
  $state = $state;

  state = { params: { option: 'E' }}
  ctrl = $controller('controllerExample', {
   $scope: scope,
   service: service,
   $log: $log
  });

  //testedStateExample = new ctrl(state);
 });

 it('"option" should be defined', function () {
  expect(state.params).toBeDefined();
 });
});
```

Comment: It's erroring on ctrl - what do you have that defined as?

Comment: I defined ctrl here:

`beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (/*params*/){
 service = _service_;
 scope = $rootScope.$new();
 $log = _$log_;
 $state = _$state_;
 ctrl = $controller('service', {
   $scope: scope, 
    service: service, 
   $log: $log, 
   $state: $state});`

Fail comment this, I edit now. xDDDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo in your controller: `$state` doesn't have `param`  property but `params`.
Besides, you have to also define `params.option` on injected `$state` object in your tests because in injected `$state` it's rather not set so your controller can't read it from `$state`  - but how to do this depends on your code details. `state.params` are set according to URL and route config but when you test standalone controller there is no URL nor route config and as a result  `$state.params` is empty. 
The best way to solve your problem is to mock injected `$state`:
Lets say that you have following controller:

```
function MyController($state) {
    this.option = $state.params.option
    ...
}
```

In your test spec you can mock `$state` service and pass this mock to your controller as argument:

```
var mockState  = {
    params: {
        option: 'TEST'
    }
}
var testedControllerInstance = new MyController(mockState)
}
... 
expect(testedControllerInstance.option).toBe('TEST');
```

## Answer update according to updated question:

You've forgotten to inject `state` into your controller:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($controller, $state,    rootScope, _$log_, _service_){
  service = _service_;
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $log = _$log_;

  var state = { params: { option: 'E' }}
  ctrl = $controller('controllerExample', {
   $scope: scope,
   service: service,
   $log: $log,
   $state: state
  });

 });
...
})
```

;

Comment: Uhm... I hope to understand you well (I feel too novice :(( ). I inject `$state`, and  now `$stateParams` too. When you inject something you must define it within a variable, right?

Comment: I need confirmed I understand this (sorry). I defined in spec.js a variable called `stateExample` and `testedStateExample` and in beforeEach (where I define ctrl) I give values similar to your example. After I change the `expect`. `TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor`. Ugh, it seems simple but when I do it I complicate my life. Without `testedStateExample` not failed but I think not use the $state, right?

Comment: Please update your question with whole relevant code (whole controller and controller tests)

Comment: Yeah, is better... I added spec.js , but now I can't teach the controller (they need my computer).

Comment: Pff, I would like cry right now with this last stupid error. I appreciate your help a lot, I do not know how to thank you properly. Thank you so much, I must confess that now I understand much more about this.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)